# Find more than 1 string with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm actually new to java and I'm happy that the regex works that I found^^ But now I need to know, how to get more than 1 string and the best would be if all would be in an array. Actually I do it like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name~(.*?)@");
Matcher m = p.matcher(response);

while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What problem you having?

Comment: As I wrote, I don't need just 1 match, I need all the matches

Comment: Your code gives you all the matches, doesn't it?

Comment: `while (m.find())` will run untill it finds all the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your results into a `List`:

```
final List<String> results = new LinkedList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    results.add(m.group());
}
```

You can then access the results in the `List` directly - if you need random access use an `ArrayList` rather than a `LinkedList`. If you need an array then simply convert it

```
final String[] resultArr = results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
```

If you're matching multiple items in a `String` you can help the regex engine out a little by matching `[^@]` and making it possessive rather than using a reluctant `.*`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name~([^@]++)@");
```